# How can we include_once a file in PhP from various folder?

Tags: php

Say we have a folder domainname.com/somelibrary/library.php

Located in domainname.com/helloworld/someplace/someplace/somephp.php

I want to include that /somelibrary/library.php

A way to do so is to find the relative path. I can do

```
include_once ('../../../somelibrary/library.php');
```

But then the include_once statement must change all the time depending on where my file is.

I can try     include_once ('/somelibrary/library.php');

It doesn't seem to work.

```
Warning: include_once(/blablabla/hello.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/romancegua/public_html/russia/test.php on line 2
```

I am very sure `/blablabla/hello.php` exist.

It's located at `/home1/romancegua/public_html/blablabla/hello.php`

So what's my solution?

Comment: I mean thats why name space and auto-load are developed ..

Comment: I suggest you get a look at how Composer and its autoloading works, it allows you to avoid this kind of relative path fiddling.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the absolute path of "somelibrary/library.php"

```
include_once('/home1/romancegua/somelibrary/library.php');
```

If you not sure how to get you can put an

```
echo __FILE__; die();
```

into library.php and call it. then it will show you the current file path.

Comment: hmmm is there a way to figure out the absolute path of the / directory in the domain? It'll be pretty useful

Comment: if you do not have ssh-access you can do also with some new php file. Make new test.php file and put <?php echo __FILE__; die(); ?> inside and call it with your browser

Answer (score 1):

Like the guys said in the comments, you should be using autoloading:

`PHP` has this feature natively:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . EXTENSION;
});

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 

$obj->sayHello();
```

Even easier, you can use namespaces and the autoloading feature offered by composer, using `psr-4`.

Example:

Add the following to your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload":{
  "psr-4" : {
    "App\\": "src/"
  }
}
```

`App` would be name of your project, and `src` is the folder for your classes.

Then use `namespace`

```
namespace App\folder;
```

---

http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: is this what wordpress use?

Comment: yes,  as you can see it here https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=spl_autoload_register

Comment: include is fine for small scripts, but then its not maintainable for projects

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define paths constants, one with the path of your site

```
define('SITE', '/home1/romancegua/public_html/');
```

and the one with your library folder

```
define('LIBRARY', SITE . 'somelibrary/');
```

here I've made two for reusability.
an then you can call your library with:

```
include_once(LIBRARY . 'library.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']..'/blablabla/hello.php');
```

That does the trick for me.